# Plotting Space time graph in python

Tags: datetime, graph, matplotlib, graphviz, space

I am searching an example where a space time graph is drawn. I went through Graphviz but cannot find relevant example. I have to plot a graph of a computer network and the network is assumed to change after 10 seconds. I can plot for one scenario but now I need to combine different graphs obtained at different time as a Space Time Graph.
I am using python for plotting But any relevant examples with any tools like Graphviz, matplotlib, networkx,etc will be helpful.

So any advice and guidelines regarding this is highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean by a Space Time graph?  My  interpretation of that phrases involves relativity which I suspect is not what you want ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_diagram ).

Comment: I want to have something like this image http://imageshack.us/a/img521/9890/spacetimegraph.png.
At time =0, node B ,C and D are connected and A is alone.
At time =10, node A and B are connected. Also C and D are connected.
And so on....

Comment: you should accept your own answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you tcaswell for your reply. I have already worked on something, so if I cannot make it that way I will dig into the way you have suggested. For now I have: 
[image]

But I want something like this:

[image]

The .dot file code used by GraphViz to create this image:

```
graph {
    rankdir=LR;
    subgraph cluster01 {
        label="t=0"
        a0 [label="A"];
        a1 [label="B"];
        a2 [label="C"];
        a5 [label="E"];
        a0 -- a1;
        a1 -- a2 ;
        a2 -- a0;
    };

    subgraph cluster02
    {
        label="t=10"
        b0 [label="A"];
        b5 [label="E"];
        b1 [label="B"];
        b2 [label="C"];

        b0 -- b1;
        b2 -- b5;
    };

    a0--b0 [style=dotted];
    a1--b1 [style=dotted];
    a2--b2 [style=dotted];
    a5--b5 [style=dotted];
}
```

I think I am not able to play around with the "rankdir" properly.

Comment: This problem is solved:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463541/subgraph-layout-in-graphviz

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using `matplotilb`.  This is minimal code.  Might be more efficient to do this with a scatter instead of individual plots for points and playing games with `NaN` for discontinuous lines, but this will work.  See [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_demo.html) for ellipse examples.  `text` [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text), or if you want to be fancier annotate [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_level(ax,t,location_map, link_pairs,shift_scale = 10):
    # add some code that adds the ellipse + time label    
    shift = np.array([0,t*shift_scale])

    # plot nodes + labels
    for key in location_map:
        pt_location = location_map[key] + shift
        ax.plot(pt_location[0],pt_location[1],'ok')
        ax.text(pt_location[0],pt_location[1],key + "%d"%t) # play with this to make it look good

    # plot connections
    for a,b in link_pairs:
        ax.plot(*(np.vstack((location_map[a],location_map[b])) + shift.T).T,color='k')
    plt.draw()


location_map = {}
location_map['A'] = np.array([0,0])
location_map['B'] = np.array([1,1])
location_map['C'] = np.array([2,0])
location_map['D'] = np.array([3,1])

link_pairs1 = [('A','B')]
link_pairs2 = [('B','C')]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
# function_that_draws_axes_marker
plot_level(gca(),0,location_map,[])
plot_level(gca(),1,location_map,link_pairs1)
plot_level(gca(),2,location_map,link_pairs2)
# function_that_draws_vertical_lines(t_range,location_map,shift_scale=10)
```