# Subgraph layout in graphviz

Tags: graphviz, rank, subgraph

I have code to display two subgraphs:

```
graph {
    rankdir=LR;
    subgraph cluster01 {
        label="t=0"
        a0 [label="A"];
        a1 [label="B"];
        a2 [label="C"];
        a5 [label="E"];
        a0 -- a1;
        a1 -- a2 ;
        a2 -- a0;
    };

    subgraph cluster02
    {
        label="t=10"
        b0 [label="A"];
        b5 [label="E"];
        b1 [label="B"];
        b2 [label="C"];

        b0 -- b1;
        b2 -- b5;
    };

    a0--b0 [style=dotted];
    a1--b1 [style=dotted];
    a2--b2 [style=dotted];
    a5--b5 [style=dotted];
}
```

This code displays two subgraphs like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F23SY.png]

But I want to have it like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUpIp.png]

I hope someone will help me fix the "rankdir" to get it done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following was achieved by using **invisible edges** and **`constraint=false`** on some edges:

[image: graphviz output]

```
graph {
    rankdir=LR;
    subgraph cluster01 {
        label="t=0";
        a0 [label="A"];
        a1 [label="B"];
        a2 [label="C"];
        a5 [label="E"];
        a0 -- a1;
        a1 -- a2;
        a2 -- a5 [style=invis];
        a2 -- a0 [constraint=false];
    };

    subgraph cluster02
    {
        label="t=10"
        b0 [label="A"];
        b5 [label="E"];
        b1 [label="B"];
        b2 [label="C"];

        b0 -- b1;
        b1 -- b2 [style=invis];
        b2 -- b5;
    };

    edge[constraint=false];
    a0--b0 [style=dotted];
    a1--b1 [style=dotted];
    a2--b2 [style=dotted];
    a5--b5 [style=dotted];
}
```

Comment: Is there definitely no way to set positions of subgraphs? (As above or below each other?)

Comment: Technically, you can set the bb (bounding box) attribute of the cluster, but you also have to set the positions (pos) of all the nodes in the graph.  Then use `neato -n`.  Doable for a graph like above, but not trivial.